# Why rollback is not working for variable table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, transactions, sql-server-2012, rollback

I have created one variable table. In my stored procedure, there are lots of transactions.

Now whenever an error occurs, I want to rollback a specific transactions which has some statements which insert or update or delete records from variable table.

This is just an example of my actual problem :

```
declare @tab table (val int)

insert into @tab select 2
insert into @tab select 3
insert into @tab select 4

select * from @tab

begin tran
begin try
    update @tab set val = 1
    select 1/0;
    commit
end try
begin catch
    rollback
end catch

select * from @tab
```

Actual output :-
[image]

My expected output is :-

[image]

So here rollback of a transaction is not working. Why it is not working here ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

You are not using a `temp` table, you are using a `variable` table.  There is a difference.

Temp tables work with transactions, variable tables don't. See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/28/sql-server-difference-temp-table-and-table-variable-effect-of-transaction/

If you were to change your variable table `@tab` to a temporary table of `#tab`, you would get your desired behavior.

Differences between temp and variable tables: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386

> I have modified my question. Thanks for your knowledge sharing. But question remains the same. Why it is not working for variable table?

The links I posted above go through that with more detail than I could.

Comment: I have modified my question. Thanks for your knowledge sharing. But question remains the same. Why it is not working for variable table?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Modifications to table variables *are* logged to the `tempdb` transaction log. But they run under internal system transactions committed after each statement - that do not participate in the surrounding user transaction.

Comment: @MartinSmith I guess I was misinformed.  `unknown` Here's a post (from Martin :O) that goes into some information on table variable storage in the log http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36296/does-large-table-variables-fill-up-logs-in-tempdb

Comment: And another one with more details on other differences. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386

Comment: @MartinSmith wow nice!  Favorited and upvoted that one, I might need that later :)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Is there anything that you don't know in Sql server :D